# Handle Soft Delete on JavaSpring and Hibernate

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa

I'm looking for a method which helps me to handle soft deletes in a db with a lot of relationships `@ManyToOne` and `@ManyToMany` without changing every single query already wrote with a `WHERE` criteria on a "disabled" flag.

The `@Where` Annotation throws jpa exception when queries are on entity in relationship with the `@Where` one due to a "not find Entity" ofc

A user of StackOv suggested me to apply a Filter on the entity and enable it just when I need, but I can't find a way to use it on Spring.

The main question is: How can I hide rows with disabled field ==1 in direct queries(i.e. StudentRep.findAll()) and related queries(i.e. BookRep.findAll(), where i'm asking just for enabled Students's books).

Is there a clean method to do this?

User

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "STUDENT")
public class Student extends Person
{
    @Field
    Boolean Disabled;

    @OneToMany
    Set<Book> books;

    /* getters and setters methods */
}
```

Book

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "BOOK")
public class Book
{
    /*...*/

    @ManyToOne
    Student student;

    /* getters and setters methods */
}
```

Comment: As stated use filters those are made for that, there are numerous tutorials describing how to do that. If you have a specific problem with enabling the filters explain what you tried not what doesn't work.

Comment: Can u pls link me any? It seems every tutorial I found does not fit my problem. Thank you

Comment: What doesn't fit? Please be a bit more clear, your questions are quite vague... How to use filters is explained in the reference guide, there isn't much more to it.

Comment: I readed in the hibernate reference that the filter is enabled on a session:
https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.6/reference/en-US/html/filters.html

I can't find a way to have the session object in spring to enabling the filter on it. Moreover i readed on a Spring Documentation page where that Session manipulating is a bad practice, so I can't find a right way to implement this solution.

Comment: `((Session) entityManager.getDelegate())` will give you the session for the current transaction, which you can use to enable the filters. Or `entityManager.unwrap(Session.class)` should be preferred in newer versions of JPA. And if you use Spring Data JPA there is a post on how to do that [here](https://dzone.com/articles/adding-hibernate-entity-level).

Comment: Ok, i'm going to try, thank you.